# Failing to download expat in crosstool-ng

Tags: crosstool-ng

I'm attempting to create a toolchain for my Raspberry Pi using my Ubuntu box.  I've installed crosstool-ng 1.24.0.  When I run `./ct-ng build`, it says that it fails to download expat.  Here's the output:

```
[INFO ]  Performing some trivial sanity checks
[WARN ]  Number of open files 1024 may not be sufficient to build the toolchain; increasing to 2048
[INFO ]  Build started 20210903.144609
[INFO ]  Building environment variables
[WARN ]  Directory '/home/daniel/src' does not exist.
[WARN ]  Will not save downloaded tarballs to local storage.
[EXTRA]  Preparing working directories
[EXTRA]  Installing user-supplied crosstool-NG configuration
[EXTRA]  =================================================================
[EXTRA]  Dumping internal crosstool-NG configuration
[EXTRA]    Building a toolchain for:
[EXTRA]      build  = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
[EXTRA]      host   = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
[EXTRA]      target = aarch64-rpi3-linux-gnu
[EXTRA]  Dumping internal crosstool-NG configuration: done in 0.18s (at 00:03)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs
[EXTRA]    Retrieving 'linux-4.20.8'
[EXTRA]    Verifying SHA512 checksum for 'linux-4.20.8.tar.xz'
[EXTRA]    Retrieving 'zlib-1.2.11'
[EXTRA]    Verifying SHA512 checksum for 'zlib-1.2.11.tar.xz'
[EXTRA]    Retrieving 'gmp-6.1.2'
[EXTRA]    Verifying SHA512 checksum for 'gmp-6.1.2.tar.xz'
[EXTRA]    Retrieving 'mpfr-4.0.2'
[EXTRA]    Verifying SHA512 checksum for 'mpfr-4.0.2.tar.xz'
[EXTRA]    Retrieving 'isl-0.20'
[EXTRA]    Verifying SHA512 checksum for 'isl-0.20.tar.xz'
[WARN ]    Downloaded file isl-0.20.tar.xz reference digest not available
[EXTRA]    Retrieving 'mpc-1.1.0'
[EXTRA]    Verifying SHA512 checksum for 'mpc-1.1.0.tar.gz'
[EXTRA]    Retrieving 'expat-2.2.6'
[ERROR]    expat: download failed
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_Abort[scripts/functions@487]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: CT_DoFetch[scripts/functions@2103]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: CT_PackageRun[scripts/functions@2063]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: CT_Fetch[scripts/functions@2174]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_expat_get[scripts/build/companion_libs/210-expat.sh@12]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_companion_libs_get[scripts/build/companion_libs.sh@15]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@648]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      https://crosstool-ng.github.io/docs/known-issues/
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  If you feel this is a bug in crosstool-NG, report it at:
[ERROR]  >>      https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/issues/
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Make sure your report includes all the information pertinent to this issue.
[ERROR]  >>  Read the bug reporting guidelines here:
[ERROR]  >>      http://crosstool-ng.github.io/support/
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 1:09.34)
[01:10] / make: *** [ct-ng:261: build] Error 1
```

I've tried manually placing a tar ball for expat 2.2.6 into `.build/tarballs` as I've seen recommended by others.  However, the error doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/issues/1479#issuecomment-900776677 suggests that the file needs to be put into the `~/src` folder.

Comment: This is not link-**only** since the answer is directly in the answer.